# formatting the login screen

Tags: html, css

I am preety new to HTML and CSS. And I also know is a very basic question. I am trying to create a login frontend the code which I am using is as shown below. Code is written by using HTML and css only

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   form {
    border: 6px solid #f1f1f1;
   }

   input[type=text]{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    margin: 16px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    margin: 16px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 10%;
   }

   button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
   }

   .cancelbtn {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #f44336;
   }

   .imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 12px 40px 12px 0;
   }

   .container {
    padding: 20px;
   }

   span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
   }

  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <center>
   <h2>Inventory Update Interface Login</h2>
  </center>
  <form method="post">
   <div class="container">
    <label>
     <b>Username</b>
    </label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
    <label>
     <b>Password</b>
    </label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
   </div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

but the problem is that I want to make the box in the center of the screen and text field to be slightly smaller in length. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add This CSS

```
.container{
  max-width:600px;
  border: 6px solid #f1f1f1;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```css
form {}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  border: 6px solid #f1f1f1;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  margin: 16px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 12px;
  margin: 16px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 10%;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 12px 40px 12px 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 20px;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h2>Inventory Update Interface Login</h2>
</center>
<form method="post">
  <div class="container">
    <label><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>
    <label><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TRY THIS 


<style>
        form {
            border: 6px solid #f1f1f1;
        }

        input[type=text]{
            width: 100%;
            padding: 8px 8px;
            margin: 16px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 2px solid #ccc;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        input[type=password] {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 8px 8px;
                margin: 16px 0;
                display: inline-block;
                border: 2px solid #ccc;
                box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        button {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 15px 35px 15px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 10%;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        button:hover {
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        .cancelbtn {
            width: auto;
            padding: 10px 18px;
            background-color: #f44336;
        }

        .imgcontainer {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 12px 40px 12px 0;
        }

        .container {
            padding: 20px;
            margin-left: 25%;
            margin-right: 25%;

        span.psw {
            float: right;
            padding-top: 16px;
        }

    </style>
```

Answer (score -1):

@nishant kumar  A part from formatting I just want to ask for learning purpose that why you have given "width: 10%;" to "button"?
Suggestion: Instead of that you may consider to use "min-width: Xpx". where "x" will be any number as per your requirement.